# How can we use addCallback function in flex

Tags: javascript, apache-flex

How can i call the flex frunction from the java script?
i am using below code which is define in below links

```
ExternalInterface.addCallback( "javascriptfunction", flexfunction);
```

http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/flex-javascript-basics-using-externalinterface

http://circlecube.com/2010/12/actionscript-as3-javascript-call-flash-to-and-from-javascript/

Answer (score 0):

You should give more context for your problem. From what I read on the tutorials, it is possible that you have omitted to add security access to your code. More precisely look here: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html#addCallback%28%29 , especially here:

> SecurityError — The containing environment belongs to a security sandbox to which the calling code does not have access. To fix this problem, follow these steps:
>     In the object tag for the SWF file in the containing HTML page, set the following parameter:

```
param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always" 

In the SWF file, add the following ActionScript:

flash.system.Security.allowDomain(sourceDomain)
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

In `flex 4.5`

Add a addcallback first, like this in your mxml

```
public function initApp():void {
        ExternalInterface.addCallback("myFlexFunction",myFunc);
}
```

`myFlexFunction` can now be accessed from your javascript.

Make your index.template.html looks like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<!-- saved from url=(0014)about:internet -->
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>addCallback() Wrapper</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="swfobject.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var swfVersionStr = "0";
            var xiSwfUrlStr = "";
            var flashvars = {};
            var params = {};
            params.quality = "high";
            params.bgcolor = "#ffffff";
            params.allowscriptaccess = "sameDomain";
            var attributes = {};
            attributes.id = "AddCallbackExample";
            attributes.name = "AddCallbackExample";
            attributes.align = "middle";
            swfobject.embedSWF(
                "AddCallbackExample.swf", "flashContent",
                "100%", "100%",
                swfVersionStr, xiSwfUrlStr,
                flashvars, params, attributes);
        </script>
    </head>
    <SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
        function callApp() {
            window.document.title = document.getElementById("newTitle").value;
            var AddCallbackExample = document.getElementById("AddCallbackExample");
            AddCallbackExample.myFlexFunction(window.document.title);
        }
    </SCRIPT>

    <body>
        <form id="f1">
            Enter a new title: <input type="text" size="30" id="newTitle" onchange="callApp()">
        </form>
        <div id="flashContent"/>
   </body>
</html>
```

and your flex application like this

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!-- wrapper/AddCallbackExample.mxml -->
<s:Application 
    xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
    xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" 
    xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" creationComplete="initApp()">
    <fx:Script>
        import flash.external.*;

         public function initApp():void {
            ExternalInterface.addCallback("myFlexFunction",myFunc);
         }  

         public function myFunc(s:String):void {
            l1.text = s;
         }
    </fx:Script>

    <s:Label id="l1"/>

</s:Application>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I am also using same way.. 
I did not catch,what i am doing in wrong. 
Do you have any idea how can i trace code one by one

Comment: 1. run the app is debug mode
2. have trace in flex
3. console.log in javascript